# Using Jest --testNamePattern=<regex> or -t option in package.json

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs

How to use Jest `--testNamePattern=<regex>` or `-t` option in package.json

```
jest -t /.*flow.spec.js$/
```

or

```
jest -t='.*flow.spec.js$'
```

Does not work.

Answer (score 7):

The confusion in this scenario is that `--testNamePattern` is used to match the name of the test within the test suite not the file. The provided example will, likely not as expected, match:

```
describe('Test suite', () => {
  test('something.flow.spec.js', () => {
    //... tests here
  });
});
```

To match by file name instead, the `--testPathPattern` argument should be used. In this case try:

```
--testPathPattern=.*flow.spec.js$
```